# Show that the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, divisibility

let $A \in M_n(F)$ be a n by n matrix with values from an unknown field $F$.

$P_A(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and $g(t) \in F[t]$ a polynomial of an unknown degree.

assume that $gcd(P_A(t),g(t))=1$

Show that $g(A)$ is invertible.

I don't understand why this is true.

Because the gcd is 1, I can safely say that $g(A) \neq 0$ due to the cayley-hamilton theorem, but why can I say anything about $det(g(A))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Using Euclidean algorithm, we can find $a(t), b(t) \in F[t]$ such that $a(t)P_A(t) + b(t)g(t) = 1$.

Comment: Ah that's right! And if we say that $t=A$, and because of cayley-hamilton, we get: $b(A)g(A)=I$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\exists\;h(t)\,,\,q(t)\in F[t]\;\;s.t.\;\;P_A(t)h(t)+g(t)q(t)=1$$

Now pass to the ring of polynomials *over the matrices* and substitute above...